# Use hive printf formatter to turn "1234" into "1.2.34"

Tags: string, hive

I hope to use the hive "printf" function, which goes off the java [formatter class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) to turn a string such as "1234" into "1.2.34".  Or, "4321" into "4.3.21", etc.  So ideally, something like this:

```
SELECT PRINTF("x.x.xx", "4321");
// -> 4.3.21
```

Is this possible?  If so, what would the format string be?

I know that I could do the same with string concat, but would rather not.  I am working in hive, "1234" is a result of an expensive regex, and I hope to get this in one step without running the regex three times or using subqueries.

EDIT: Just to clarify, this is in hive.  Sorry for not making that clear in advance.

Comment: Is this the only thing the formatter needs to do? Is it always 4 digits or there's some more logic here? With a String of known format, you could always build up the one you want by grabbing the characters at certain indices and inserting the dots between.

Comment: It's always 4 digits.  I know I could grab the indices and insert the dots between, but that would require calculating the original string three times.  Such as SUBSTR(REGEXP(...),0,1) || "." || SUBSTR(REGEXP(...),1,1) || "." || SUBSTR(REGEXP(...),2,2).  This is my last resort, just trying to see if there is a better way to do it:)

Comment: You can't store the result as a variable for easier access? I don't know anything about Hive so I apologize if this is a stupid question.

Comment: I could, but that would also be suboptimal as then I'd have to reorganize my query and store an additional set of intermediate results.  That's also an option, but just trying to avoid it at all costs

Comment: If it will always be 4 digits (not less, no more), then you can do something like `char[] chrDigits = theString.toCharArray(); String s = String.format("%c.%c.%c%c", chrDigits[0], chrDigits[1], chrDigits[2], chrDigits[3])` but it will be an ugly solution, maybe if you explain more about the problem you could have a better answer.

Comment: I don't think you need to create new variables.. Just make a helper method that takes in this String and returns what you want?

Comment: sorry, just to clarify, this is in hive and not java.  The printf functions uses java internally, but i'm trying to figure out the hive syntax

Answer (score 0):

This may help for further needs.

```
formatter = new DecimalFormat("#.#");
s = formatter.format(-1234.567);         // -1234.6
```

**EDIT.**
Not sure if you can accomplish this using Formatter if there's no decimal dot in it.
Seems like some previous work with the string needs to be done. Check David's answer.

Comment: How's this supposed to format a number with no decimal places using the dot operator?

Comment: yout insight is right, this can't help the purpose. Editing answer in a minute.

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] stringArray = "1234".split("");
// This will have a leading array entry of empty string, so chop it off somehow
// EDIT: had the pattern wrong, fixed it
System.out.println(String.format("%s.%s.%s%s", Arrays.copyOfRange(stringArray, 1, stringArray.length)));
```

Comment: check that the output must be _x.x.xx_, not _x.x.x.x_ as you suggest.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Edited the answer for the pattern requested.